# What is .DS_Store and why am I suspecting it has broken my web project?

Tags: image, macos

I am working on a college assignment and am having a huge problem. 
Everything was fine until I noticed a strange '**.DS_Store**' file in the main folder containing all my images, html, css and .js files.

Now my webpages look like this:

[image: Chrome view of index.html]

An old screen grab - I had just finished adding a custom sprite and tweaking a flexslider before this all happened:

[image: An old screen-grab from Chrome]

I was trying to find some more information about this '.DS_Store' file. I can't find much online. Nor can I find any postings about similar problems. I did find [this](http://danilo.ariadoss.com/how-to-recursively-remove-ds_store-files-on-mac-os-x/) though but am hesitant to start deleting files from terminal.

However, I strongly suspect it has something to do with this '.DS_Store' file.

I have tried to solve this problem by:

- Importing all images back into photoshop and saving to a new folder.
- Importing all code and script to a pain-text editor and then back into Coda, Wrangler, Dreamweaver on Mac and Notepad++ on a Windows machine).

I am still getting the same effect when I try to view the pages in Chrome, IE, Mozilla - broken images and no formatting. Not compiling.

[image: Broken Images]

Does anyone know anything about this? I would HUGELY appreciate some information on how I can fix this.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it has nothing to do with graphic design.

Comment: This is better suited for StackOverflow. But it seems your problem is that your html is not reading your css. Triple check all code to be _absolutely_ sure you have the right paths. You can also rename the mystery file by adding something to the filename and see if that sorts it.

Comment: I solved the problem. And I am feeling a bit silly. I panicked, seeing that a hidden file was making itself visible and thought it was to blame. It was, however, Dreamweaver just deciding on a whim not to recognise my file-paths. I noticed the colour had changed but overlooked it because the paths were correct. I had to delete and retype. Strange. Sorry for time wasting.

Answer (score 2):

`.DS_STORE` would not have broken your web project at all.

From wikipedia:

> DS_Store files are automatically created by Mac OSX Finder in browsed directories. **These files contain information about system configuration.**

System configuration files would not affect your web project at all.

Comment: Thanks Zen :) all sorted.

Answer (score 0):

.DS_store is just a hidden file with info about the system. If you haven't touched it, there is probably another problem. Maybe you moved a folder? Made a typo? Added or removed code?